# How do I disable shipping in some of my woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce online shop that offers shipping to most products. Some of the products are for local pickup. I've tried setting a class on shipping zones with cost equal to zero and assigning the class on the products. But so far, the checkout still displays the shipping cost. Is there any way where some products will not have a shipping cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for plugin solution, try [WooCommerce Conditional Shipping and Payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/). By using this plugin, you could add restrictions on certain product or product categories.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go check it out

Answer (score 2):

You've might want to look into the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter, which allows you to filter the set of shipping options that are available to the customer. An example would be something like this:

```
<?php
// add this snippet to functions.php:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', function ( $rates, $package ) {
    // examine $package for products. this could be a whitelist of specific 
    // products that you wish to be treated in a special manner...
    $special_ids             = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
    $special_product_present = false;
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $line_item['product_id'], $special_ids ) ) {
            $special_product_present = true;
        }
    }

    $rates = array_filter( $rates, function ( $r ) use ( $special_product_present ) {
        // do some logic here to return true (for rates that you wish to be displayed), or false.
        // example: only allow shipping methods that start with "local"
        if ( $special_product_present ) {
            return preg_match( '/^local/', strtolower( $r->label ) );
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } );

    return $rates;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This [blog post here](https://calebburks.com/customize-woocommerce-shipping-rates/) shows some variations on that idea using this hook, including how to customize the available rates based on shopping cart value, customer's country, number of items in the cart, etc. And here's the source code: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/v2.2.3/includes/class-wc-shipping.php#L366

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider your suggest.